# How to extract an array of another array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to get an array stored in another array, so that i can send it to a method.

My array is:

```
double[][] myArray = {myA1,myA2,myA3};
```

and the contain of arrays:

```
myA1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
myA2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
myA3 = {1,2,3,4};
```

How can I extract the array "**myA1**" of **myArray** ???.
If possible stored in another array.

Comment: How would you extract a `double` from a `double[]`? Now, how would you extract a `double[]` from a `double[][]`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "extract"?  Are you just trying to reference `myArray[0]` or do you need to copy it off somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as easy as

```
double[] a1 = myArray[0];
```

Comment: at least, could you please post up some explanation? :)

Comment: @KickButtowski Seriously?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes why do you think other people are as expert as you are? how this answer will help anybody who wants to learn. at least,some explanation is gonna be valuable because if you see my answers I try to give away explanations as much as I can. be my guest and stop by :)

Comment: Using lots of words doesn't necessarily imply that an answer is any good.

Comment: I tried to add some explanation but I don't know what I can add for something that obvious...  Just one thing that people may overlook: `double[][]` in Java is simply an "Array of [Array of double]".  Once you understand that, the answer is obvious

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could do it like -

```
double[] myA1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
double[] myA2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
double[] myA3 = {1,2,3,4};
double[][] myArray = {myA1,myA2,myA3};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
double[] arr = myArray[0];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output is

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

And then `arr` contains the contents from `myA1` and prints as -

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from zero.

```
double[] arr={1,2,3};
// now arr[0]=1 and arr[1]=2 and so on
```

Now let's see what happen in here.

```
double[] myA1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
double[] myA2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
double[] myA3 = {1,2,3,4};
double[][] myArray = {myA1,myA2,myA3};

// then myArray[0] =myA1
double[] myArray0= myArray[0];// 0th index of myArray is myA1
```